# Debugging the error occurred in jboss-log4j.xml

Tags: log4j, jboss5.x

Where can I find out any errors which might have occurred during configuration of `jboss-log4j.xml`?

Errors include simple typing mistake to making an entry for `appender` but not for `category name`.

Am facing a problem where log is not writing to the specified file name but its getting written to server's `server.log`. So, I would like to debug where am making mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just log4j. So, for example, -Dlog4j.debug=true will spill some information for you. See the log4j doc for more details.